# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, sql, laravel

here I am trying to display real visitor data based on the ip record in the visitor table.
from the record the data saved is the record for each ip that visits 1x refresh = 1 record.

therefore I use "distinct", but the graph does not display any data.

```
$vissitu = visitor::distinct()->get('ip');
        $charte = Charts::database($vissitu, 'bar', 'highcharts')
                  ->title("Kunjungan Visitor Bulanan")
                  ->elementLabel("Total Visitor")
                  ->dimensions(700, 400)
                  ->responsive(true)
                  ->groupByMonth();
```

Comment: Hi @Elan Felani, You have used `highcharts` tag, but the problem seems to be more related with `laravel-highcharts` package. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a JS code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection pluck and format the result to array.

try something like this:

```
$vissitu = visitor::distinct()->pluck('name')->toArray();
```

Comment: now this appears "Call to a member function filter() on array" f